# "PGSSLMODE=allow pg_dump -h host -p 5432 " seems to have no effect on SSL Mode

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

I'm trying to connect to the remote PostgreSQL server to do a database dump of some tables.  I'm using
`PGSSLMODE=allow pg_dump -h host -p 5432`

However it fails everytime with `pg_dump: error: connection to database "schema_name" failed: FATAL:  SSL connection is required. Please specify SSL options and retry. FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "x.x.x.x", user "admin", database "schema_name", SSL on`

Comment: Just an FYI I have also tried ```export PGSSLMODE=allow```  and ```PGSSLMODE=allow``` all with the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's working as it should:

First, it tries an unencrypted connection (`allow` prefers unencrypted connections). That gives you the `FATAL: SSL connection is required` from the server.

Then it tries an encrypted connection, but no rule in `pg_hba.conf` allows that connection, so you are again rejected.

Solution: add an appropriate `pg_hba.conf` line and use `SSLMODE=require` to attempt only an encrypted connection and avoid the first error message.

Comment: What your saying makes sense, however how would pgAdmin make the connection then to this server?  That works.

Comment: @GhostProgrammer  if pgAdmin is able to connect, it must be coming from a different host, or connecting to a different server or different dbname or different username, or using an SSH tunnel.

Comment: pgAdmin is coming from the same client machine.  Only difference is it is coming from a docker image of pgAdmin, instead of the command line I'm using for pg_dump and psql.

Comment: And I have not setup anything in pgAdmin for SSH tunnel.

Comment: Tip: turn on `log_connections` on the server and compare the log entries for a working connection and your failed connection. That will allow you to figure out the difference.

Comment: I don't think a docker image is really the same host, at least not as far as other containers are concerned.  Isn't that one of the main thing docker provides, virtually defined networking?